# Update data after display

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bindings

In my Angular app I have an array of messages each of which has an array of pages on which it should be displayed:

```
[{
    message: 'Foo',
    showOnPage: [1, 3],
    viewed: false
},{
    message: 'Bar',
    showOnPage: [2, 3],
    viewed: true
}]
```

This is fetched from the server when the app loads and then kept in sync with push events from the server. It is not reloaded when navigating between pages.

I have a directive to display these messages which takes the array and page ID and only shows the messages for the current page which are not yet viewed. So far so good.

Now I want to set `viewed` to `true` once the message has been displayed once. If I do it as soon as it is displayed then the data binding will immediately remove it from view. If I do it on scope `$destroy` it works so long as the user navigates to another angular page. If the user refreshes or closes the tab, or navigates to an external URL then `viewed` stays `false`. I can't use `onbeforeunload` because I need to do an AJAX request to update the message on the server. And I don't want to use bind once as that would prevent any new messages from being displayed.

Updating a property *after* it is shown seems like a fairly reasonable requirement but I'm stuck for ideas on how to implement it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the array when it's returned from the server. When the items are viewed, update viewed = true in the original array, do your AJAX request to update the message on the server, but use viewed on the copy to determine which messages to display.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a boolean for `viewed`, make it an integer, which is incremented as soon as it is eligible for display. The template should only render it when `viewed` === 1